# For each manager_id between 202 and 203, show the number of employees each manager supervises

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

**For each manager_id between 202 and 203**

- show the number of employees each manager supervises
- Show only those managers who manage more than 2 employees.

The table info:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (  
    Employee_ID     INT     NOT NULL,  
    First_Name      VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,  
    Last_Name       VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,  
    Dept_Code       VARCHAR(6)  NOT NULL,  
    Hire_Date       DATE        NULL,  
    Credit_Limit    NUMERIC(8,2)    NULL,  
    Phone_Ext       INT     NULL,  
    Manager_ID      INT     NULL);  

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (201,'Susan','Brown','Exe','01-Jun-1998',30.00,3484,NULL);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (202,'Jim','Kern','Sal','16-Aug-1999',25.00,8722,201);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(203,'Martha','Woods','Shp','02-Feb-2004',25.00,7591,201);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(204,'Ellen','Owens','Sal','01-Jul-2003',15.00,6830,202);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(205,'Henry','Perkins','Sal','01-Mar-2000',25.00,5286,202);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(206,'Carol','Rose','Act','','',NULL,NULL);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(207,'Dan','Smith','Shp','01-Dec-2004',25.00,2259,203);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(208,'Fred','Campbell','Shp','01-Apr-2003',30.00,1752,203);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(209,'Paula','Jacobs','Mkt','17-Mar-1999',15.00,3357,201);  
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(210,'Nancy','Hoffman','Sal','16-Feb-2004',25.00,2974,203);
```

Comment: 1) Don't tag products not involved. Remove all those not involved.

Comment: 2) Proper formatting makes your question much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing reading on basic sql selects and grouping. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT manager_id
    ,count(distinct employee_id) employees_managed
from employee
where manager_id in (202, 203)
group by 1
having count(distinct employee_id) > 2
```

you basically want to count employee ids for each manager. And filter on manager id. and then filter on employee count greater than 2.

Comment: thank you, any recommendations on which source would be best to learn from?

Comment: start with w3 school

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will do that now!

Comment: Try my answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get the answer:

```
    SELECT Manager_ID, COUNT(Employee_ID) AS EmployeeCount
    FROM dbo.Employee
    WHERE Manager_ID BETWEEN 202 AND 203
    GROUP BY Manager_ID
    HAVING COUNT(1) >2
```